# section numbering in tex4ht using memoir class with article option

Tags: sectioning, memoir, tex4ht, latex-to-word

`tex4ht` seems to ignore the `article` option in the `memoir` class. I say this because section numbers (and the corresponding cross-references) appear as 0.1, 0.2, etc. instead of 1, 2, etc. when outputting to `.odt` using `tex4ht` (but not when using `xetex`).

Is this a bug? If not, is there a way for me to modify this behavior?

Comment: Oops, I realized that I was totally confused about this one. I had assumed that the `article` option was supposed to do the trick, but now I realize that I needed to add an extra line (`\renewcommand*{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}`) to get `xetex` to do it right. And now `tex4ht` does it right too. What is the right TeX.SE protocol? Should I delete/close this question? Should I "answer" my own question and thus close it? Or should I just leave it as is with apologies for being too quick to post it?

Comment: I think it would be best to add your own answer with the correct code, to help people with the same issue in the future.

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in a comment, I realized that the problem had nothing to do with `tex4ht` but rather I was simply mistaken about `memoir`'s default. So the answer is:

To achieve the desired output, one must add the line `\renewcommand*{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}` to the preamble.

MWE:

```
%!TEX TS-program = xelatex
%!TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode

\documentclass[12pt,article,oldfontcommands]{memoir}

\renewcommand*{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}

\begin{document}

\section{first section}

Should be section 1 but is instead section 0.1.

\end{document}
```